# I am unable to access document field from cloud firestore and show it in a statefulwidget class in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to acess the uname field of the current loggedin user .
I added uname in the registration screen like this :

```
 onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final newuser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email ?? 'error',
                        password: password ?? 'error',
                      );
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('Users')
                          .add({' uname': username});

                      if (newuser != null) {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => home()),
                        );
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  }
```

But I dont know how to acess it from another file or more specifically I want to acess it on the profile screen .

**How can I acess the uname field from firestore in flutter?**

[image: cloudconsole]

Comment: where do you call showDisplayName?

Comment: and also could you include inside code of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?

Comment: I have edited my question ..I want to acess the uname document field using document id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the document in the `initState` and set the value of string using `setState`

Code:

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  String? name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print(value.data()?[' uname'];
      setState(() {
        name = value.data()?[' uname'];
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child:
              name != null ? Text(name!) : const CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

---

##### Note: This is not recommended ⚠

*As future method is called inside the `initState(){}` it is heavily discouraged to do so as it slows down the process of building the widget and also not considered as a good practice.*

##### Use `FutureBuilder` for this:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)  
            .get(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
          return Text(data['fullName']); // Your valid data here
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to what you want is to set the document ID in the collection("Users") same as the uid of the user authenticated. So fetching details or in this case, uname will be easier.

For creating doc with docID same as user uid:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(newUser.uid)
    .add({' uname': username});
```

For fetching details:

```
final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .get();
```