# How can I acess a document field using document id from cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access my document field `uname` from cloud firestore . I made the uid and document id same and  when I tried to access the document field it shows the error `Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform`

[image]

This is my code

```
  
class test extends StatefulWidget {
  const test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _testState createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> {
 

  final userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) => print((value.data() ? ["uname"])));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(()),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to `get` the data of the `DocumentSnapshot` using `data()` and then access the `uname`.

Try to replace `value` with `value.data()`

And access using uname using: `value.data()?["uname"]`

```
final userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) => print((value.data()?["uname"]));
```

Comment: it is still showing the error "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Comment: I had typing mistake . Please check the edited code above. This works perfectly fine

Comment: Yes I got it,May I know how can I access it inside my Text() widget in flutter ?

Comment: Your question is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973110/13431819 please refer the same, and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1):

the return of `get()` is actually a `DocumentSnapshot`, you need to access the `data()` to get the `Map<String, dynamic>` of your document's fields, then access the `"uname"` value from it like this:

```
final userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value)  {
      final documentData = value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // this is your document data           
      print(documentData["uname"]) // this is you what need to access the name field
      });
```